Concatenate group-wise in a non-blocking way in Nextflow
I want to split a nextflow workflow into separate chunks (vehicle types), then split these chunks even further (vehicles) and then report as soon as all workers for a specific vehicle type are done.

Currently nextflow main.nf results in:
 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.2

Launching `nextflow_pipeline/main.nf` [amazing_bell] DSL2 - revision: aae9cee085

executor >  local (11)
[6e/28da8a] start     | 1 of 1 ✔
[36/743eea] step1 (2) | 2 of 2 ✔
[cd/50083f] step2 (6) | 6 of 6 ✔
[5f/a823c3] step3 (1) | 2 of 2 ✔
step2: boats1

step2: boats2

step2: cars2

step2: cars3

step2: cars1

step2: cars4

all cars are done

all boats are done


What I would like instead is:
 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.2

Launching `nextflow_pipeline/main.nf` [amazing_bell] DSL2 - revision: aae9cee085

executor >  local (11)
[6e/28da8a] start     | 1 of 1 ✔
[36/743eea] step1 (2) | 2 of 2 ✔
[cd/50083f] step2 (6) | 6 of 6 ✔
[5f/a823c3] step3 (1) | 2 of 2 ✔
step2: boats1

step2: boats2

all boats are done

step2: cars2

step2: cars3

step2: cars1

step2: cars4

all cars are done


Minimal reproducible example:
process  start {
    output:
        path "vehicle_types.list", emit: vehicle_type

    """
    #!/usr/bin/python3

with open('vehicle_types.list', 'w') as fout:
    for vehicle in ['boats', 'cars']:
        fout.write(vehicle + "\\n")
    """
}

process  step1 {
    debug true

    input:
        val vehicle_type

    output:
        path "vehicles.list", emit: vehicles

    """
    #!/usr/bin/python3

import time
if "${vehicle_type}" == 'boats':
    n = 2
else:
    n = 4
with open('vehicles.list', 'w') as fout:
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(2)
        fout.write("${vehicle_type}" + str(i + 1) + "\\n")
    """
}

process  step2 {
    debug true

    input:
        val vehicle

    output:
        path "not_needed.txt", emit: hacky_output

    """
    echo step2: ${vehicle}
    echo hello > not_needed.txt
    """
}

process  step3 {
    debug true

    input:
        val vehicle_type
        val hacky_variable_to_ensure_step2_completed

    """
    echo "all ${vehicle_type} are done"
    """
}

workflow {
    main:
        start()
        start.out.vehicle_type.splitText().map{it -> it.trim()}.set{vehicle_type}
        step1(vehicle_type)
        step1.out.vehicles.splitText().map{it -> it.trim()}.set{vehicles}
        step2(vehicles)
        step3(vehicle_type, step2.out.hacky_output.last())
}

Currently step3 is being blocked by the .last(). I want to concat the results from step2 in a non-blocking way as soon as all the workers for a specific vehicle type are done instead of waiting till all workers for step2 are done. How do I achieve this?

You can use the built-in groupKey() function to define the expected size of each group. Then call with the groupTuple operator, for example:
process step1 {
    tag "$vehicle_type"
    debug true

    input:
    val vehicle_type

    output:
    tuple val(vehicle_type), path("vehicles.list"), emit: vehicles

    """
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    import time

    n = 2 if "${vehicle_type}" == 'boats' else 4
    with open('vehicles.list', 'w') as fout:
        for i in range(n):
            time.sleep(2)
            fout.write("${vehicle_type}" + str(i + 1) + "\\n")
    """
}

process step2 {
    tag "$vehicle_type"
    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(vehicle_type), val(vehicle)

    output:
    tuple val(vehicle_type), path("not_needed.txt"), emit: hacky_output

    """
    echo "step2: ${vehicle}" && touch not_needed.txt
    """
}

process step3 {
    tag "$vehicle_type"
    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(vehicle_type), path("txt")

    """
    echo "all ${vehicle_type} are done"
    """
}

workflow {

    vehicle_types = Channel.of('boats', 'cars')

    step1( vehicle_types )

    step1.out.vehicles
        .map { vehicle_type, vehicle_list ->
            def vehicles = vehicle_list.readLines()
            def group_key =  groupKey( vehicle_type, vehicles.size() )

            tuple( group_key, vehicles )
        }
        .transpose()
        .set { vehicles }

    step2( vehicles )
    
    step3( step2.out.hacky_output.groupTuple() )
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.3

Launching `main.nf` [modest_nightingale] DSL2 - revision: 49168943ed

executor >  local (10)
[b1/dae30f] step1 (cars)  [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[4a/018f10] step2 (cars)  [100%] 6 of 6 ✔
[eb/bab138] step3 (cars)  [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
step2: boats2

step2: boats1

all boats are done

step2: cars1

step2: cars2

step2: cars3

step2: cars4

all cars are done



Your solution works perfectly, thanks a lot Steve!

It sounds like you're looking for the collect() operator if you want step3 to not even start until all of step2 is complete.
This may work:
step3(vehicle_type, step2.out.hacky_output.collect())


Collect also doesn't seem to be it. I want step3 to start as soon as all related step2 workers of it are done, not as soon as all step2 workers are done.

Ah, I mixed up the what you had and what you wanted. I'll have a think.
